# How to run the Angular folder in existing project?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

This is the application folder structure and I have specified the paths as well as and tried several ways to run but I have an error like . Can Anyone give the right solution to start the angular folder.

Whole application structure:

[image: Whole application structure]

Error while start the angular.js app:

[image: Error while start the angular.js app]

package.json:

[image: package.json]

Comment: Probably you should post your code/errors/package.json as text, not as images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it's Angular.js project, not Angular. so ng comang will not work

look inside gulpfile.js for command to start your app

or run in project's root folder `gulp --tasks`

Comment: const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js');
});

Comment: This my gulp.js file but I didn't find any starting command

Comment: look at your package.json "scripts" section